# How to execute a terminal program and perform an action when it closes in vimscript

Tags: vim

I'd like to write a Vim command that does the following:

1. Make a new split.
2. Launch a terminal program.
3. Wait for the program to stop and close the split.
4. Read the output produced in the second step into the original buffer.

This seems like a very common work flow, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
The problem is in steps 3 and 4. As a test I defined:

```
function MyExitFunction(a,b,c)
  close
  read blah
endfunction
```

Then did:

```
:new | call termopen('fzf>blah',{on_exit:MyExitFunction}
```

which does start the terminal and close the split after the program is done. The `read` command, however, seems to do nothing. Perhaps it reads the input into a wrong split?

What should I do to get the actual program output into my current buffer?

Note, `fzf` is not the actual program I'm running, but it works a bit like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a command that cleanly outputs to `stdout`, then you simply need `:read !<command>`.

If you want interactivity, i.e. reading from `stdin` first, then you should probably run it inside a terminal with `:vs | te` and then yank the output over. Vim doesn't have a clean and easy way to interop with interactive scripts, so this is probably as good as it's gonna get.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `:vert term` at the end?

Comment: That works too, but it's all the same thing. Just open a terminal in a vertical split.

Comment: Well, that is what I'm currently doing. I launch my program in terminal, go to insert, use it, get out of insert, select stuff I need, yank it, close the buffer and paste. Which is quite bit of work.

 I'd like to make it automatic.